# Remote: Permission to repo denied at github

Tags: git, github

Now I am trying to use my personal account to push code to my personal repo. However, my current laptop also has set up my company git account.

That's why I tried to set up different account in terminal. However, after trying various video, including this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fnSRBRiQIU8. I still get the error below:

`remote: Permission to user2/repo.git denied to user1.`

Could anyone provide any insight to make it work? At least, let me commit as User2, but not User1. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If two users are creating problems, you can try out using two ssh keys, one for personal use and one for company's ?

Comment: @DeepakPatankar Thanks for replying! Do you mean creating two different rsa file? I. did create two ssh keys. However, for some reason, I have already added that to  .ssh/config and also update git name --  "git config user.name user2". But just don't understand why user1 is still the one to  make the push.

Comment: Assuming you have configured `~/.ssh/config`, try `ssh-add -D`, and then run for example `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal`.

Comment: @syohey Oh, yep, it works! I did try it earlier. For some reason, I still have two key attached. After making sure, it only has one rsa key `id_rs_personal`. Thanks a lot! Feel free to add your answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: @HaoyuChen I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `ssh-agent` can only handle one ssh key per session, so it is necessary to run `ssh-add -D` to drop all the keys first, and then add the key you want to use with:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/<rsa-key-file>
```

If your `~/.ssh/config` looks like the following:

```
# personal
Host github.com
    HostName github.com-personal
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
```

then you can run `ssh -T git@github.com-personal` to confirm that your key is successfully authenticated :)